# Advanced filters using 2 rows, one of them with no criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create an optional OR condition using advanced filters.

The table has 2 columns for dates. One date is the initial date and the other is the final date.

My goal is:

- To show only rows that match the newest initial date.
  OR
- To show rows that match empty initial date rows.

The problem is that I want the second row of criteria to be optional but if I leave the second row of criteria empty the advanced filter won't work.

I'm using Excel XP.

Comment: For Newest / Earliest date use MIN(Range) for date and use as criteria to filter. And for empty date put `=` as criteria.

Comment: @RajeshS Thanks. But the thing is that filter does not work if I leave the second row of criteria without any criteria. I don't know if it is normal or not. I want to have 2 rows of criteria defined for Advanced filtering but I want to not always use the second row.

Comment: Hi @Lorthas,, if U put 2 criteria in Row, works as AND like City="NY" and ZIP ="12345", and if U write 2 criteria in 2 riows then works as OR ,, better share some sample data & expected output will help us to fix the issue.